# Shiny app working locally but not deployed on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

I'm in a difficult situation to figure out how to publish shiny app online.

Can't find any solution in the older questions.

The app works locally perfect but its impossible to put it online.

when I run the log, show just this:

> **Error** in serverInfo(server) : server named 'rpubs.com' does not exist

on the part

> "Markers": Line 14 - Paths should be to files within the project
>   directory. Error in sheets_fun(path) : Evaluation error:
>   path[1]="database.xls".

The file *.xlsx is already in the same folder of the *rmd.

Could any one help me I have no idea how to solve this issue. I'm now in two weeks trying to solve this.
that is to grab a job, and I will appreciate a lot if anyone tell me how to make it works